# real time broadcasting in not working in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, broadcast

I have added broadcasting in the rails model, please have a look at the below files
.

**Comment model**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord

  validates :body, presence: true
  belongs_to :post
  after_create_commit { broadcast_append_to "comments_#{self.post_id}", partial: "posts/comment" }

end
```

**Post model**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

end
```

**app/views/posts/index.html.erb**

```
<h1 class="text-center m-4 text-success">Posts</h1>
<div id="posts">
    <div class="row">
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <%= render post %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app/views/posts/_post.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
    <div class="card border-0" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p>
                <span class="comment">
                    <%= link_to fa_icon("comment"),"#", data: { action: "click->like#comment",comment_url: new_post_comment_path(post.id) } %>
                </span>
            </p>
            <div id="add_comment_<%= post.id %>"></div>
            <h5 class="card-title"><%= post.title %></h5>
            <p class="card-text"><%= post.description %></p>
            <strong>Comments</strong>
            <%= turbo_stream_from "comments_#{post.id}" %>
            <%= turbo_frame_tag "comments_#{post.id}" do %>
                <div id="add_comments_<%= post.id %>">
                    <% post.comments.each do |comment_post| %>
                        <%= render partial: "posts/comment", locals: { comment: comment_post } %>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app/views/posts/_comment.html.erb**

```
<p id="comment_<%= comment.id %>" data-controller="comment"><%= comment.body %>
    &nbsp;
    <span>
        <%= link_to "edit",post_comment_edit_path(comment.post,comment), data: { turbo_method: :post }  %>
    </span>
    &nbsp;
    <span><%= link_to "delete", post_comment_path(comment.post,comment), data: { turbo_method: :delete } %></span>
    &nbsp;
    <span><%= commentUpdatedAt(comment) %> ago</span>
</p>
```

I have checked with `binding.pry`, in the comment model does not get `post_id` when creating a comment, so the targets are different.

Please help me

Comment: could anyone please help me with this problem, it's urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the above answer,

**app/models/comment.rb** file

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord

  validates :body, presence: true
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  
  after_create_commit :set_comment
  after_update_commit :update_comment
  after_destroy_commit :destroy_comment

  private

  def set_comment
    broadcast_append_to "add_comments_#{self.post.id}", partial: "posts/comment", target: "add_comments_#{self.post.id}"
  end

  def update_comment
    broadcast_update_to "comment_#{self.id}", partial: "posts/comment", target: "comment_#{self.id}"
  end

  def destroy_comment
    broadcast_remove_to "comment_#{self.id}"
  end
  

end
```

**app/views/posts/_post.html.erb** file

```
<strong>Comments</strong>
            <%= turbo_stream_from "add_comments_#{post.id}" %>
            <div id="add_comments_<%= post.id %>">
                <% post.comments.each do |comment_post| %>
                    <%= render partial: "posts/comment", locals: { comment: comment_post } %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
```

**app/views/posts/_comment.html.erb** file

```
<%= turbo_stream_from "comment_#{comment.id}" %>
<p id="comment_<%= comment.id %>" data-controller="comment"><%= comment.body %>
    &nbsp;
    <span>
        <%= link_to "edit",post_comment_edit_path(comment.post,comment), data: { turbo_method: :post }  %>
    </span>
    &nbsp;
    <span><%= link_to "delete", post_comment_path(comment.post,comment), data: { turbo_method: :delete } %></span>
    &nbsp;
    <span>
        <%= link_to "reply",replyComment_post_comment_index_path(comment.post), data: { turbo_method: :post }  %>
    </span>&nbsp;
    <span><%= commentUpdatedAt(comment) %> ago</span>
</p>
```

The solution is working well as I expected.